# Antlr - Parsing Multiline #define for C.g4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 to parse C code.
I want to parse multiline #defines alongwith C.g4 provided in
[C.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4)

But the grammar mentioned in the link above does not support preprocessor directives, so I have added the following new rules to support preprocessing.

[Link to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766854/get-preprocessor-lines-with-antlr4-with-parsing-c-code)

```
Whitespace
    :   [ \t]+
        -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

Newline
    :   (   '\r' '\n'?
        |   '\n'
        )
        -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

BlockComment
    :   '/*' .*? '*/'
    ;

LineComment
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]*
    ;


IncludeBlock
     :   '#' Whitespace? 'include' ~[\r\n]*
     ;

DefineStart
    :     '#' Whitespace? 'define'
    ;

DefineBlock
     :   DefineStart ~[\r\n]*
     ;

    MultiDefine
    :   DefineStart MultiDefineBody
    ;

MultiDefineBody
    :   [\\] [\r\n]+ MultiDefineBody
    |   ~[\r\n]
    ;



preprocessorDeclaration
    :   includeDeclaration
    |   defineDeclaration
    ;

includeDeclaration
    :   IncludeBlock
    ;

defineDeclaration
    :   DefineBlock | MultiDefine
    ;

comment
    :   BlockComment
    |   LineComment
    ;

declaration
    :   declarationSpecifiers initDeclaratorList ';'
    |   declarationSpecifiers ';'
    |   staticAssertDeclaration
    |   preprocessorDeclaration
    |   comment
    ;
```

It works only for Single line pre-processor directives if MultiBlock rule is removed
But for multiline #defines it is not working.

Any help will be appreciated

By Multiline #define I mean

```
#define MACRO(num, str) {\
            printf("%d", num);\
            printf(" is");\
            printf(" %s number", str);\
            printf("\n");\
           }
```

Basically I need to find a grammar that can parse the above block

Comment: You actually don't have a rule called `MultiBlock`. So which rule(s) are you referring to?

Comment: There is no MultiBlock.... I talking about all the rules related to MultiDefine

Comment: Ah okay... So all `Multi...` right? And if they are present in the grammar the single line instructions no longer work?

Comment: I want to parse a entire c file with functions, comments, and preprocessor directives.... Grammer is given in the git link..
It works fine with only single line preprocessor statements...even with this grammer
But fails when functions or other c elements are added or multi-line defines are added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm shamelessly copying part of my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308045/antlr-parser-for-alpha-numeric-words-which-may-have-whitespace-in-between):

> This is because ANTLR's lexer matches "first come, first serve". That
>   means it will tray to match the given input with the first specified
>   (in the source code) rule and if that one can match the input, it
>   won't try to match it with the other ones.

In your case the input sequence `DefineStart \\\r\n` (where `DefineStart` stands for an input-sequence corresponsing to the respective rule) will be matched by `DefineBlock` because the `\\` is being consumed by the `~[\r\n]*` construct.

You now have two possibilities: Either you tweak your current set of rules in order to circumvent this problem or (my sugestion) you simply use one rule for matching a define-statement (single and multiline).

Such a merged rule could look like this:

```
DefineBlock:
    DefineStart (~[\\\r\n] | '\\\\' '\r'? '\n' | '\\'. )*
;
```

Note that this code is untested but it should read like this: Match `DefineStart` and afterwards an arbitrary long character sequence matching the following pattern: The current character is either not `\`, `\r` or `\n`, it is an escaped newline or a backslash followed by an arbitrary character.
This should allow for the wished newline-escaping.

Comment: Now it resolves input text containing any kind of preprocessor statements....
But when it encounters something other than preprocessor statement then it is not able to resolve

Comment: You can refer the entire grammar without preprocessor in the Github link https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4

Comment: Huh? Wasn't it the point to tokenize preprocessor statements? Or is the problem that when using the complete grammar the preprocessor statements are no longer tokenize correctly?

Comment: The point was to include preprocessing in that grammer which was done only the multiline define was failing.
I have applied your advice to the other rules and now it is working 
thanks